# First error message is displayed against all text boxes which have invalid values

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, idataerrorinfo

I have a WPF user control having 3 text boxes like Id, Name, Address. Each text box binds to separate property in the View Model. I have implemented `IDataErrorInfo` in VM to show validation/error message related to each property. I use the following XAML for my text box.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="CustomTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"></Border>
                            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                            <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Foreground="Red" Height="30" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="!" ToolTip="{Binding Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Adorner}}"></TextBlock>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Problem:

Lets say I enter an invalid value for the Name and then "without correcting it" I move on to Id text box and enter invalid value in Id text box too. I was expecting that I will see "Id is invalid" message against Id text box and "Name is invalid" message against Name text box. But it does not work that way. I always see first error message ("Name is invalid") against Name as well as Id text box too.

How can I get it working as expected? How to write XAML so that it can display error message relevant to each text box?

Comment: Post the code you used in the ViewModel.

Comment: @VVN : VM is returning correct error messages as expected.

Comment: could you post the `xaml` with the textboxes for id, name? thx